# Does BatchFetch change the fetch type?

Tags: jpa-2.0, eclipselink, fetch, batch-processing

I am using EclipseLink 2.1.0 in my Java EE application and optimized the loading of nested entity lists using `@BatchFetch`. Now I'm curious if this Annotation will change the fetch mode, meaning does it change the lazy/eager loading set using `fetch = FetchType.EAGER`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Batching is independent of lazy/eager fetching, and only controls how the query to fetch the referenced objects behave, not when it occurs.

Comment: Is there any documentation specifying this independence? I thought that it would be like that, but I need it proven.

Comment: I don't think you'll find documentation precisely because they are independent concepts.  A simple test proves the point - set logging to finest, read your entity, log something, then access the relationship.